# How host dotCMS application?

Tags: web-hosting, dotcms

I am developing an application in **dotCMS**. I created a new URL and in that URL added some html pages.But this is on the **dotCMS**. How to host this application like any other HTML based web site.Please help me to resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

You can either name your host with the new URL you created or just edit your host and give the newly created URL as an alias for the host.